# pandas .to_csv() takes more memory than expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, memory

I have a data set, which represents some voltage vs time dependence. The data set has 32 MSamples (32 X 1024 X 1024), each sample is a 16-bit voltage value and 64-bit time value. I represent this dataset as a pandas DataFrame, which has 32 X 1024 X 1024 rows (number of samples) and two columns (voltage and time).

I save this DataFrame to CSV using pandas .to_csv(). The resulting CSV file size is 1.5 GB. That said, each voltage is 16 bits or 2 bytes, and each time is 64 bits or 8 bytes, so each row is 2+8=10 bytes. I expected the entire file to be 10 X (32 X 1024 X 1024) = 320 MB.

So I am missing a factor of about 5 here. Could somebody explain this discrepancy and how this .to_csv() works? Thanks.

---

UPDATE:
To provide more code. I have a list of 32 MSamples, so the number of samples is

```
N_SAMPLES = 32 * 1024 * 1024
```

and each sample is a 16-bit value (2 bytes). These samples are saved in a list called `DATA`. These are voltages acquired over a period of time, I call this period `DURATION`. Then I generate a list of times when each sample was acquired by doing this:

```
t = np.linspace(0,DURATION,num=N_SAMPLES)
```

I assume by doing this, each element of `t` is np.float64, so each element of `t` is a 64-bit value (8 bytes). Then I create the dictionary:

```
data = {\
"Time [s]": t,
"Output [V]": DATA
}
```

Then I create the pandas DataFrame and save it to CSV:

```
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataFrame.to_csv('output.csv', mode='w')
```

If my math is correct, each row is 2+8=10 bytes, and there are 32 X 1024 X 1024 rows. So I expect the size of the CSV to be 320MB, but it is actually 1.5GB. What am I missing?

Comment: What is `(16 + 64)/8)`?

Comment: One guess is that it is not saved as a 16-bit value and it is transformed to 64 in csv. Besides, csv internal formatting itself could be more expensive than what you are expecting and increase it a little bit more. If you are very worried about size you might try other formats like parquet.

Comment: csv files are typically comma separated text files.  Are you certain you are storing bytes rather than string characters that look likes bytes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "That said, each voltage is 16 bits or 2 bytes, and each time is 64 bits or 8 bytes, so each row is 2+8=10 bytes. I expected the entire file to be 10 X (32 X 1024 X 1024) = 320 MB." you seem to fundamentally misunderstand something: CSV files are **text**. You aren't saving raw binary data. You are creating a text file that is in the "comma seperated values" format.

Comment: so suppose you have the np.float64: `3.1415926535989` ... that requires 8 bytes in memory. But if you *save that to a text file*, it requires *a byte per character*. So it requires 15 bytes in your text file. Note, this sometimes means text will *save* you memory, say, you have a bunch of numbers like `3.12` or  `1.9`, then those require 2-3 bytes instead of 8. Not in your case, apparently

Comment: Why are you using pandas here at all? Is it really just to save a CSV? Why use CSV? If you care about memory, use `numpy.save` to save a compact, binary representation of your data that will use memory in the way you seem to expect

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just convert first time and integers and then writes file without index:

```
data = {
"Time [s]": t.astype(np.int64),  # Convert time to 64-bit integer
"Output [V]": np.array(DATA, dtype=np.int16)  # Convert voltage to 16-bit 
integer
}

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataFrame.to_csv('output.csv', mode='w', index=False, header=False)
```